# IntelliJ IDEA seems not to support Django Framework

Tags: python, django, ide, intellij-idea

Django Framework not listed in IntelliJ IDEA editions comparison website. I'm planning to buy this nifty IDE but only if it truly supports Django just like PyCharm.

Looking at their site, it doesn't seem to support it...

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Does it support it or not? Why is it not listed then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django Framework is supported in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. We will fix this page shortly.

Comment: Thank you! Your software seems very high quality.

Comment: It does not support it in my installation.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely a site bug, which would be better taken up with them, but yeah, it *does* support it.  Here's a screenshot from IDEA Ultimate 11 (which would still be valid with 12):

[image: Confirming Django in IDEA Ultimate.]